# scrapy shell returns proper values but spider returns nothing

Tags: python, scrapy

My code:

```
import scrapy


class FlightsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "flights"

start_urls = [
        'https://www.fly540.com/flights/nairobi-to-mombasa?isoneway=0"&"currency=KES"&"depairportcode=NBO"&"arrvairportcode=MBA"&"date_from=Fri%2C+10+Dec+2021"&"date_to=Fri%2C+17+Dec+2021"&"adult_no=1"&"children_no=0"&"infant_no=0"&"searchFlight="&"change_flight='
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    for flight in response.css('div.fly5-flights.fly5-depart.th div.fly5-results table.table tr'):
        yield {
            'departureAirport': flight.css('td span.flfrom::text')[0].get()
            }
```

When using scrapy shell using the exact same link this is what I get:

```
>>> for flight in response.css('.fly5-flights.fly5-depart.th .fly5-results table.table tr'):
...      departureAirport = flight.css('td span.flfrom::text')[0].get()
...      print(dict(departureAirport=departureAirport))
...
{'departureAirport': ' Jomo Kenyatta International airport, Nairobi'}
{'departureAirport': ' Jomo Kenyatta International airport, Nairobi'}
```

But when I run the spider it returns nothing. I run it with `scrapy crawl flights -o flights.json` but the json is empty

The source url:

> https://www.fly540.com/flights/nairobi-to-mombasa?isoneway=0&currency=KES&depairportcode=NBO&arrvairportcode=MBA&date_from=Fri%2C+10+Dec+2021&date_to=Fri%2C+17+Dec+2021&adult_no=1&children_no=0&infant_no=0&searchFlight=&change_flight=

Answer (score 1):

The second url is working with scrapy but not in shell and  the first url is not working with scrapy but  with shell and why is it happening is unknown to me.

scrapy with second url:

```
import scrapy

class FlightsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "flights"

    start_urls = ['https://www.fly540.com/flights/nairobi-to-mombasa?isoneway=0&currency=KES&depairportcode=NBO&arrvairportcode=MBA&date_from=Fri%2C+10+Dec+2021&date_to=Fri%2C+17+Dec+2021&adult_no=1&children_no=0&infant_no=0&searchFlight=&change_flight=']


    def parse(self, response):
        # for flight in response.css('.fly5-flights.fly5-depart.th .fly5-results table.table tr'):
        #     departureAirport = flight.css('td span.flfrom::text')[0].get()
        #     print(dict(departureAirport=departureAirport))

        for flight in response.css('div.fly5-flights.fly5-depart.th div.fly5-results table.table tr'):
            yield {'departureAirport': flight.css('td span.flfrom::text')[0].get()}
```

Output:

```
{'departureAirport': ' Jomo Kenyatta International airport, Nairobi'}
```